# Ajax - After success response, goes to error block - Permission denied to access property "apply"

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a function that looks as below -

```
    function myFunc(param1, param2 ...) {

 // Some code

  // Loop through the array with the jQuery each function:
        $.each(myArr, function (k, arrProp) {       

 // The makeCall function returns a ajaxObject so the object gets put in var promise
            var dbExecResult = runMyQuery(k, param1, param2 etc);

 // Now fill the success function in this ajaxObject (could also use .error() or .done() )
            dbExecResult.success(function (response) {

// When success, call the function and use the values out of the array above
                myOnSuccessFunc();
            });

            dbExecResult.error(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    }
    ;
```

The response comes back fine( The result I expect to see) from the ajax POST operation. However, instead going to `Success`, it goes to `error` block !!

I've read a few posts on this now but, haven't been able to fix the problem.

Could I please request help to figure out this problem please? Is there a way to call a function right after the response arrives(I mean no success/failure block)

Comment: Tried substituting `.then()` for  `.success`, `.error`?

Comment: Thank you guest. Does `.then()` execute the callback say, irrespective of the return code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the F12 tools in your browser to see what comes across the network
- Use the debugger keyword and step through the jQuery code, it's surprisingly readable

The only time I remember seeing errors with Permission denied have been when I've tried to call server calls that don't exist

Comment: Hello Tony. Thank you. I've inspected the result on Chrome & firefox sing firebug. As mentioned int eh question, the result of the POST call is the result I expect to see.

Comment: You are inside a foreach call so I assume there are multiple Ajax calls? Do you see the results of all of them?

Comment: You're right in your understanding. Yes, all the ajax call results come back fine & all of them go to the error block :)

Comment: Can't you put the debugger keyword in the error block, see the call stack, find the top level and put a breakpoint there?

Comment: Thank you Tony. I did that actually before posting the question. I had to restart the server to get it working. Didn't need any code change. I don't know why this is, but it seems to work. Thank you very much.